# What is the point of coins in Sonic racing?

Tags: sonic-all-stars-racing-transformed

When playing in the grand prix mode of Sonic and All Stars Racing Transformed (steam version), what is the point of collecting coins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Gold Coins** can be used  to get a bonus item before the race, if you're lucky. You need to go to one of the jackpot machines in World Tour to use it, but if you play a normal race then the jackpot machine will show up when loading the level.

You can manually access the slot machine through Career, there is a slot machine in each zone. Basically, you gamble away five coins in an attempt to win a random bonus for your next race. They'll be brought up during Grand Prix before you start the race (loading screen). Keep in mind, the maximum amount of coins you can hold at one time is ninety-nine coins.

Comment: Wait there is two kinds of coins? I never saw slot machines and i am in the second world now. What about star coins?

Comment: You do mean "Sonic All Stars Racing Transformed" for Steam right? But you'll have to excuse me, I didn't mean Star 'coins' I simply meant "stars" as in the ones you get from completing challenges (harder difficulty = more stars) in order to unlock characters in Grand Tour.

Comment: Oh ok, then now I get it, because I only saw one type of coins :) please remove that so I can accept it :)

Comment: Done, glad I could help. :)